# Angular2 example, I convert typescript to es5, get route error, how?

Tags: angular

I'm learning angular2. I want to convert typescript to es5, doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

I run es5 code, I get the following error in my console

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): 
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'of' of undefined
>   platform-browser.umd.js:1900

Any pointers as to what I may be doing wrong?

**typescript "app/app.routes.ts":**

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroesComponent
  }
];

export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**I write with es5 "app/app.routes.js":**

```
(function(app) {
  console.log(ng.router.RouterConfig);
  console.log(ng.router.RouteConfig);
  const routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'heroes', component: app.HeroesComponent}
  ];

  app.appRouterProviders = ng.router.provideRouter(routes);
  console.log(app.appRouterProviders);
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

**I find "ng.router.RouteConfig" and "ng.router.RouterConfig" are undefined.**

**typescript "app/app.component.ts":**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { HeroService }     from './hero.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <a [routerLink]="['/heroes']">Heroes</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [
    HeroService
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

**I write with es5 "app/app.component.js":**

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <a [routerLink]="['/heroes']">Heroes</a>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      `
      directives: [ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
      providers: [app.HeroService]
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: [app.HeroService, function(heroService) {
        this.heroService = heroService;
        this.title = 'Tour of Heroes';
      }]
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

**typescript "app/main.ts":**

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { appRouterProviders } from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  appRouterProviders
]);
```

**I write with es5 "app/main.js":**

```
(function(app) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        ng.platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrap(app.AppComponent, [app.appRouterProviders]);
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

**index.html:**

```
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfill -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/bundles/router-deprecated.umd.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Load our 'modules' -->
    <script src='app/hero.js'></script>
    <script src='app/hero.service.js'></script>
    <script src='app/mock-heroes.js'></script>
    <script src='app/hero-detail.component.js'></script>
    <script src='app/heroes.component.js'></script>
    <script src='app/app.component.js'></script>
    <script src='app/app.routes.js'></script>
    <script src='app/main.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completing the Angular 2 Example, Tour Of Heroes, the Routing section, use ES5.

I upload code to [github](https://github.com/fantianyi/Angular-2-Example---Tour-Of-Heroes---6-Routing---ES5).

I am using the 2.0.0-RC5 bundle. I can not solve the proble using the 2.0.0-RC4 bundle!

flowing the part code:

**app.routes.js**

```
(function(app) {
  app.routing = ng.router.RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'dashboard', component: app.DashboardComponent},
    {path: 'heroes', component: app.HeroesComponent},
    {path: 'detail/:id', component: app.HeroDetailComponent}
  ]);
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```